# Playing Spotify music and audio simultaneously

Tags: spotify

I have developed an iOS App which plays music from the users music library simultaneously with audio files which are included in the app. I have hired a developer to make several changes in the app, one of which enables the user to use their "Spotify" playlists instead of their "Music" playlists, if they have a spotify account.  He tells me it is impossible for this functionality to work with the Spotify API.

Can someone please help me as I really need this functionality to work??

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with the Web API, however, take a look at [CocoaLibSpotify](https://github.com/spotify/cocoalibspotify) which is a Mac and iOS library that allows you to access a user's Spotify playlists and play tracks.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any developers who are familiar with CocoaLibSpotify who are happy to solve this problem for me?

Comment: Well, I work for Spotify and wrote CocoaLibSpotify. However, we can't write your app for you. CocoaLibSpotify is well documented and has lots of sample code — any competent iOS developer should have no problem working with it.